# Efficient Ring Buffer (FIFO)

Tags: python, networking, circular-list, tcp

I need to implement a Ring Buffer/FIFO for data coming from a TCP socket.

It must support the following operations:

- Append a the recv()'ed chunk of bytes.
- Allow me to peek at the beginning of the buffer, since i get differently-sized packets, and I must decode a small fixed-size header to know how many bytes to process.
- Remove a chunk of bytes from the beginning of the buffer for processing.

I guess my needs are pretty standard for a TCP-based streaming protocol, but surprisingly I have never found a "best practice" method for doing this.

There are similar questions on SO already, most suggest to use `collections.deque`, which is fine but has some shortcomings that must be worked around for my needs:

- It doesn't easily allow peeking.
- It doesn't allow removal of chunks of bytes.

Mixing various suggestions I came up with the following implementation, which seems working but I wonder: can I do any better, performance-wise? Removing a single byte at a time in `get()` doesn't look optimal at all.

```
import collections
import itertools

class RingBuffer (object):
    """Ring buffer"""
    def __init__ (self, size = 4096):
            self._buf = collections.deque (maxlen = size)

    def put (self, data):
            """Adds data to the end of the buffer"""
            self._buf.extend (data)

    def get (self, size):
            """Retrieves data from the beginning of the buffer"""
            data = str ()
            for i in xrange (size):
                    data += self._buf.popleft ()
            return data

    def peek (self, size):
            """\"Peeks\" at the beginning of the buffer (i.e.: retrieves data without removing them from the buffer)"""
            return str (bytearray (itertools.islice (self._buf, size)))

    def len (self):
            """Returns the length of the buffer"""
            return len (self._buf)
```

If you are wondering why I am returning a string from `peek()`, that is because I need to process its return value with `struct.unpack_from()`.

Comment: Just a though but using a `StringIO` instance as you buffer would enable easier peeking and getting chunks of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you’re stuck using one-pop-at-a-time if you want to get multiple elements at once.

I found this quote from one of the `collections` developers on Stack Overflow about [using pop() for many elements in a deque](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9507636/1558022):

> There is no multi-pop method for deques.

The OP on that question had a very similar construction to you (they were saving the data to a list rather than a str), and he said:

> Yes, it is correct. Yes, it is reasonably efficient though it can be further sped-up with boundmethods and itertools. No, it isn't stupid :-)

I don’t know enough about boundmethods or itertools to know what he was suggesting.

---

That doesn’t seem particularly helpful, so here are a few other comments on your general coding style:

- You shouldn’t have a space immediately before the opening parens that starts a list of arguments to a function. (PEP 8: [*Pet Peeves*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#pet-peeves))
- It’s also recommended that you don’t have a space around the equals sign for keyword arguments or default values. (PEP 8: [*Other Recommendations*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations))
- In the interest of using descriptive variable names, I see no reason not to extend the length of the variable name `_buf` to `_buffer`. Characters are cheap.
- Lines should be limited to 79 characters (PEP 8: [*Maximum Line Length*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length)), which includes docstrings: specifically, the docstring for `peek()`.
- If you have a single double-quote within a triple-quoted string, you don’t need to escape it. You only need to escape quotes within a triple-quoted string if you have three of them at once.
- The docstring for `RingBuffer()` is almost useless. It tells me nothing that I couldn’t have learnt from the name of the class.

And a few comments on your `get()` method in particular:

- In the for loop, your index variable is named `i`, but you never use the value of this variable. It’s common practice to give unused index variables the name `_`, to make it explicit that the value of this variable is unimportant. That is,

  ```
  for _ in xrange(size):
      data += self._buf.popleft()
  ```
- It used to be the case that it was better to construct a list of strings and then call `join()` on the list than be continually appending to strings, but I think that’s fixed in newer versions of Python.

  Regardless, I happen to have a personal preference for that construction. It makes the method slightly shorter:

  ```
  def alt_get(self, size):
      """Retrieves data from the beginning of the buffer."""
      data = ''.join(self._buf.popleft() for _ in xrange(size))
      return data
  ```

  But I think that’s entirely personal preference: I did an short performance test, and I couldn’t see any difference between this and your `get()` method.
- Suppose I have an empty ring buffer, and I try to `get()` an element from it:

  ```
  r = RingBuffer()
  r.get()
  ```

  The user sees the IndexError that arises from trying to pop an empty deque:

  ```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "buffer.py", line 29, in <module>
      r.get(1)
    File "buffer.py", line 17, in get
      data += self._buf.popleft ()
  IndexError: pop from an empty deque
  ```

  Unless you knew that RingBuffer() was using a deque under the hood, this error message would be confusing. I’d recommend having a custom error message to explain that somebody’s trying to get more items than you have to give.

  It’s also worth noting that if you use a `try … except` block here, the buffer will be emptied before you notice, and the contents could be lost. You need a check before you access anything from the buffer. Something like this:

  ```
  def get(self, size):
      """Retrieves data from the beginning of the buffer"""
      if size > len(self._buf):
          raise IndexError("Too many items: trying to access %d items "
                           "from a buffer of length %d" % (size, len(self)))
      data = [self._buf.popleft() for _ in xrange(size)]
      return data
  ```

  Your `peak()` method doesn't suffer from this problem.

Comment: A "bound method" is a "[method object](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/method.html#method-objects)" — it's what you get when you evaluate `obj.method`. If you evaluate `m = obj.method` once and then call `m(args)` many times, this is faster than calling `obj.method(args)` because the method lookup is only done once.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, @alexwlchan. I was already aware of most of your observations, I just omitted them for brevity (apart from the whitespace thing, which stems from my C background and my eyes are just trained to see code that way). Anyway it still puzzles me how surprisingly difficult it is to find a working Ring Buffer implementation with those requirements, even in C/C++! Maybe I am tackling the TCP buffering problem the wrong way? What's the best practice in this case?